# Sencha Touch2 General and external database related questions

Tags: mysql, sencha-touch, extjs

If I develop on Sencha Touch2, I would be able to create Apps and sell it through Google play store and Apple Market Store?

Can I code "on button click" action in Java ? And from that code call a web service and retrieve it's output?

What is Sencha's recommendation if I need to do SELECT/UPDATE/INSERT operations and stored procedure calls to a database preferably MySQL?

Please respond if you can answer any of the above questions

Answer (score 1):

No it's not possible to code an "on button click" action in Java because Sencha uses the JavaScript framework.

For connecting to the database you need to use SQLite, see [here](https://github.com/tomalex0/SenchaTouch-SqliteProxy).